# Print all day-dates between two dates

Tags: python, datetime

For example:

```
from datetime import date

d1 = date(2008,8,15)
d2 = date(2008,9,15)
```

I'm looking for simple code to print all dates in-between:

```
2008,8,15  
2008,8,16  
2008,8,17  
...  
2008,9,14  
2008,9,15
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Answer (score 496, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

start_date = date(2008, 8, 15) 
end_date = date(2008, 9, 15)    # perhaps date.now()

delta = end_date - start_date   # returns timedelta

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = start_date + timedelta(days=i)
    print(day)
```

The output:

```
2008-08-15
2008-08-16
...
2008-09-13
2008-09-14
2008-09-15
```

Your question asks for dates in-between but I believe you meant including the start and end points, so they are included.  To remove the end date, delete the "+ 1" at the end of the range function.  To remove the start date, insert a 1 argument to the beginning of the range function.

Comment: Hello all, i tried it but It prints only the last day, i need full list day
dates_list = []
result = d1 + td(days=i)
dates_list.append(result)
print(result) It prints only the last day, how to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like your loop is wrong somehow.  Please reply with the value of your `range(delta.days)`.

Comment: Timedelta with days always adds multiples of 24h. So if you cross a switch to day light savings time, you are off by one hour (each being at 1am). Going in the other direction you even have a different day, each at 11pm. One of the reasons to use UTC...

Comment: This uses the Date class, so time is not a factor.

Comment: @GringoSuave this is not working for Leap years,it add the Feb 29 even in Leap years, Can you fix ?

Comment: @GringoSuave If I want to get date list as ['20190322', '20190323',.......], what to do? Thankyou :-)

Comment: @RSJohn , look up `python strftime`.  If you don't mind dashes in between `date.isoformat()` is the best way.

Answer (score 58):

Using a list comprehension:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

d1 = date(2008,8,15)
d2 = date(2008,9,15)

# this will give you a list containing all of the dates
dd = [d1 + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((d2-d1).days + 1)]

for d in dd:
    print d

# you can't join dates, so if you want to use join, you need to
# cast to a string in the list comprehension:
ddd = [str(d1 + timedelta(days=x)) for x in range((d2-d1).days + 1)]
# now you can join
print "\n".join(ddd)
```

Answer (score 19):

Essentially the same as Gringo Suave's answer, but with a generator:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def datetime_range(start=None, end=None):
    span = end - start
    for i in xrange(span.days + 1):
        yield start + timedelta(days=i)
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
In: list(datetime_range(start=datetime(2014, 1, 1), end=datetime(2014, 1, 5)))
Out: 
[datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 3, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5, 0, 0)]
```

Or like this:

```
In []: for date in datetime_range(start=datetime(2014, 1, 1), end=datetime(2014, 1, 5)):
   ...:     print date
   ...:     
2014-01-01 00:00:00
2014-01-02 00:00:00
2014-01-03 00:00:00
2014-01-04 00:00:00
2014-01-05 00:00:00
```

Comment: I prefer the generator idea, it can always be a helpers function somewhere in the code; However, it certainly lack type and sanity check.  `start` and `end` args default set to None is asking for errors.

Comment: `for i in xrange(span.days + 1):` is causing errors, had to change it to `or i in range(span.days + 1):`

Comment: The other answer is a generator on Python 3, this Python 2 code is now obsolete.

Answer (score 8):

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.date(2008,8,15)
d2 = datetime.date(2008,9,15)
diff = d2 - d1
for i in range(diff.days + 1):
    print (d1 + datetime.timedelta(i)).isoformat()
```

Comment: print((d1 + datetime.timedelta(i)).isoformat())

Answer (score 4):

```
import datetime

begin = datetime.date(2008, 8, 15)
end = datetime.date(2008, 9, 15)

next_day = begin
while True:
    if next_day > end:
        break
    print next_day
    next_day += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```