# How to create dict from date (in strings) range?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two dates as strings:

```
start = '2015-01-01'
end = '2015-03-23'
```

And I want to create dict like this (I use OrderedDict):

```
date_dict = {
    '2015-01-01': [something],
    '2015-01-02': [something],
    '2015-01-03': [something],
    '2015-01-04': [something],
    [...]
    '2015-03-22': [something],
    '2015-03-23': [something],
}
```

How to generate keys from this two strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7274316/4907653

Comment: Are your date always saved as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the below code to generate the keys -

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td
start = '2015-01-01'
end = '2015-03-23'
sd = dt.strptime(start,'%Y-%m-%d')
ed = dt.strptime(end,'%Y-%m-%d')
delta = ed - sd
for i in range(delta.days+1):
    dict[sd + td(days=i)] = <something>
```