# Get all dates between startdate and enddate columns

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have created a dataframe using below python code.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

d = {'StartDate': pd.Series(["2018-11-01", "2018-11-04", "2018-11-06"]),
     'EndDate': pd.Series(["2018-11-03", "2018-11-05", "2018-11-10"])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])
```

I would like to have a column as Date, which will be having the dates between startdate and enddate columns values.

Expected Output:-

[image]

I did tried the same thing in R which i am familiar already.

```
R Script:- 

   df1 %>%
   rowwise() %>% 
   do(data.frame(.[1:2], date = seq(.$min_date, .$max_date, by = "1 day")))
```

Can anyone please suggest me?

Comment: I "suggest" you give it a try yourself, then come back with any specific problems you're having. Then we'll be happy to help with those.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274267/print-all-day-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: @Sociopath No, they want the sequence of every single date (day) between the given bounds. A question which has already been answered ^^^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `date_range` + `merge`

You can create a date range using [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) and merge the two dataframes setting as `outer` the merging type. Finally you can fill the missing values using the `ffill` method in [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), which will propagate the last valid observation forward to next valid backfill.

```
print(df)

  StartDate    EndDate
0 2018-11-01 2018-11-03
1 2018-11-04 2018-11-05
2 2018-11-06 2018-11-10

dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=df.min().StartDate, 
                     end=df.max().EndDate), columns=['Date'])
pd.merge(left=dates, right=df, left_on='Date', right_on='StartDate', 
         how='outer').fillna(method='ffill')

    Date  StartDate    EndDate
0 2018-11-01 2018-11-01 2018-11-03
1 2018-11-02 2018-11-01 2018-11-03
2 2018-11-03 2018-11-01 2018-11-03
3 2018-11-04 2018-11-04 2018-11-05
4 2018-11-05 2018-11-04 2018-11-05
5 2018-11-06 2018-11-06 2018-11-10
6 2018-11-07 2018-11-06 2018-11-10
7 2018-11-08 2018-11-06 2018-11-10
8 2018-11-09 2018-11-06 2018-11-10
9 2018-11-10 2018-11-06 2018-11-10
```

Comment: this only works if the start/end period don't over lap

Comment: For the same result when start/end periods overlap, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68227664/14463396