# How can we get range of dates (ex. from Jan 2000 to Dec 2010 ) in the format of 01012000-31122012) using itertools.permutations?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools, brute-force

I am basically creating a bruteforcer in python

combos=itertools.permutations("i34U^hP-",8)

This is where I need to find the regex instead of that given inside the brackets.

Comment: Do you want all the possible date ranges between Jan 2000 and Dec 2010?

Comment: yes friend. i need to bruteforce within the range.

Comment: Can you use pandas?

Comment: I can use anything. I was actually creating a python script for bruteforcing site. I am aware of username. And for password I know it as in the format of ddmmyyyy . Actually it is the dob of the user.  If the login is successful it is redirected the logged in page or else it is looped till the range of dates.  I am using this https://coderinaero.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/brute-force-a-website-login-in-python/ for it .

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274267/print-all-day-dates-between-two-dates).

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

d1 = date(2000, 1, 1)  # start date
d2 = date(2010, 12, 31)  # end date

delta = d2 - d1         # timedelta

combos = []

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    formatted = (d1 + timedelta(i)).strftime("%d%m%Y")
    combos.append(d1 + timedelta(i))
```

I answered the question because is quite general and the answer can be applied in a lot of different contexts. **REMEMBER YOU NEED TO BE AUTHORIZED TO PERFORM A BRUTE FORCE.** Do not try to hack in a system without a bounty program, of if you haven't been preauthorized by the owner of the website.