# Getting the list of dates given a string in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a string in python which is

```
date="200601"
```

which represents in `2006 January`

How do I get the list of dates in that particular month in the '`yyyy-mm-dd`' format

and also how do I iterate over `200601` to `201903` ie. getting the all values between the two month wise.

```
example 200601,200602,200603...
```

Thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: @DeepSpace He probably meant January 2006. :3

Comment: I think he meant 2006. :D

Comment: edited the response I meant 2006

Comment: Can you guys help me out?

Comment: @AbeerSheikh see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the `dates` in the `month` of that `year` in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
date = "200601"

import datetime, calendar
num_days = calendar.monthrange(int(date[:-2]), int(date[4:]))[1]
print([datetime.date(int(date[:-2]), int(date[4:]), day).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for day in range(1, num_days+1)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['2006-01-01', '2006-01-02', '2006-01-03', '2006-01-04', '2006-01-05', '2006-01-06', '2006-01-07', '2006-01-08', '2006-01-09', '2006-01-10', '2006-01-11', '2006-01-12', '2006-01-13', '2006-01-14', '2006-01-15', '2006-01-16', '2006-01-17', '2006-01-18', '2006-01-19', '2006-01-20', '2006-01-21', '2006-01-22', '2006-01-23', '2006-01-24', '2006-01-25', '2006-01-26', '2006-01-27', '2006-01-28', '2006-01-29', '2006-01-30', '2006-01-31']
```

And for the second question:

[Print all day-dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274267/print-all-day-dates-between-two-dates)

**EDIT**:

Continuing from the comments under this answer:

```
print([datetime.date(int(date[:-2]), int(date[4:]), day).strftime("%Y%d") for day in range(1, num_days+1)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['200601', '200602', '200603', '200604', '200605', '200606', '200607', '200608', '200609', '200610', '200611', '200612', '200613', '200614', '200615', '200616', '200617', '200618', '200619', '200620', '200621', '200622', '200623', '200624', '200625', '200626', '200627', '200628', '200629', '200630', '200631']
```

Comment: Thank you but can you tell me how do i get it in the following format  [200601,200602,200603.....] . Iteration over months

Comment: @AbeerSheikh sure just replace `strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` with `strftime("%Y%d")`

Comment: @AbeerSheikh if the answer helped you may accept it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers