# TheGuardian API - Script crashes

Tags: python-3.x, api, sentiment-analysis

```
import json
import requests
from os import makedirs
from os.path import join, exists
from datetime import date, timedelta

ARTICLES_DIR = join('tempdata', 'articles')
makedirs(ARTICLES_DIR, exist_ok=True)

API_ENDPOINT = 'http://content.guardianapis.com/search'
my_params = {
    'q': 'coronavirus,stock,covid',
    'sectionID': 'business',
    'from-date': "2019-01-01",
    'to-date': "2020-09-30",
    'order-by': "newest",
    'show-fields': 'all',
    'page-size': 300,
    'api-key': '### my cryptic key ###'
}


# day iteration from here:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274267/print-all-day-dates-between-two-dates
start_date = date(2019, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2020,9, 30)
dayrange = range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)
for daycount in dayrange:
    dt = start_date + timedelta(days=daycount)
    datestr = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    fname = join(ARTICLES_DIR, datestr + '.json')
    if not exists(fname):
        # then let's download it
        print("Downloading", datestr)
        all_results = []
        my_params['from-date'] = datestr
        my_params['to-date'] = datestr
        current_page = 1
        total_pages = 1
        while current_page <= total_pages:
            print("...page", current_page)
            my_params['page'] = current_page
            resp = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, my_params)
            data = resp.json()
            all_results.extend(data['response']['results'])
            # if there is more than one page
            current_page += 1
            total_pages = data['response']['pages']

        with open(fname, 'w') as f:
            print("Writing to", fname)

            # re-serialize it for pretty indentation
            f.write(json.dumps(all_results, indent=2))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-f04b4f0fe9ed> in <module>
     49             resp = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, my_params)
     50             data = resp.json()
---> 51             all_results.extend(data['response']['results'])
     52             # if there is more than one page
     53             current_page += 1

KeyError: 'results'
```

> Same error occurs for 'pages'
>
> At first there was no issues and was able to run it. Download crashed after 2020-03-24. Since then can't get the code running again.

I'm referring to Line 51 and 54. At least at this point the codes crashes.
Not sure how to get rid of the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding the error message would be the first step - it compains about a missing key. Check if `data['response']['results']` is present (hint: it is not) and check what exactly the structure of your `data['response']` is.

Fortunately one can use the api parameter `'test'` so we can help using that key:

```
my_params = {
    'q': 'coronavirus,stock,covid',
    'sectionID': 'business',
    'from-date': "2019-01-01",
    'to-date': "2020-09-30",
    'order-by': "newest",
    'show-fields': 'all',
    'page-size': 300,
    'api-key': 'test'    # test key for that API
}
```

On running, I get the same exception, inspect `data['response']` and get:

[image: number too big]

Lets see what parameters are given, shall we?

```
my_params = {
    'q': 'coronavirus,stock,covid',
    'sectionID': 'business',
    'from-date': "2019-01-01",
    'to-date': "2020-09-30",
    'order-by': "newest",
    'show-fields': 'all',
    'page-size': 300,      # TOO BIG
    'api-key': 'test'
}
```

Fix that to 200 and you'll get

```
Downloading 2019-01-01
...page 1
Writing to tempdata\articles\2019-01-01.json
Downloading 2019-01-02
...page 1
Writing to tempdata\articles\2019-01-02.json
Downloading 2019-01-03
...page 1
Writing to tempdata\articles\2019-01-03.json
Downloading 2019-01-04
...page 1
Writing to tempdata\articles\2019-01-04.json
Downloading 2019-01-05
[snipp]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer and helpful explanation! really appreciated!