# Finding dates between two consecutive dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the a pandas dataframe in this format:

```
Dates
11-Feb-18
18-Feb-18
03-Mar-18
25-Mar-18
29-Mar-18
04-Apr-18
08-Apr-18
14-Apr-18
17-Apr-18
30-Apr-18
04-May-18
```

I want to find dates between two consecutive dates. In this example I want to make a new column which will contain dates between two consecutive dates. For example between 11-Feb-18 and 18-Feb-18, I will get all the dates between these two dates.

I tried this code but it's throwing me error:

```
pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(df_new['Time.[Day]'].loc[i].diff(-1)))})
```

Comment: could you make a mockup table of your desired output? I'm not sure whether you want the "dates" column to become expanded by all the missing dates, or whether you want a second column that holds all missing dates as a list.

Comment: In any case, this link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274267/print-all-day-dates-between-two-dates While this is a duplicate, look for the list comprehension in one the secon answer. Imho, its the most elegant way to create a date range

Comment: @Racooner I want to create a new column in the dataframe which will contain all the dates between two consecutive dates

Comment: Anjali, have you tried my code? Please, be kind to comment whats wrong. It was tested. The result is a dataframe with dates you want

Answer (score 0):

This works with dataframes, adding a new column containing the requested list
It iterates over the column 1, preparing a list of lists for column 2.

At the and it creates a new dataframe column and assigns the prepared values to it.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pp
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
in_betweens = []

for i in range(len(df["dates"])-1):
    d = datetime.strptime(df["dates"][i],"%d-%b-%y")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(df["dates"][i+1],"%d-%b-%y")
        
    d = d + timedelta(days=1)
    in_between = []
    while d < d2:
        in_between.append(d.strftime("%d-%b-%y"))
        d = d + timedelta(days=1)


    in_betweens.append(in_between)
    
in_betweens.append([])
df["in_betwens"] = in_betweens

df.head()
```

Comment: But how can it be done for a dataframe? As I am dealing with a Dataframe

Comment: I have added a dataframe based version, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a column with the list of dates tat are missing in between, this shoudl work. This could be more efficient and it has to work around the `NaT` in the last row and becomes a bit longer as intended, but gives you the result.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Dates" : 
        ["11-Feb-18", "18-Feb-18", "03-Mar-18", "25-Mar-18", "29-Mar-18", "04-Apr-18",
        "08-Apr-18", "14-Apr-18", "17-Apr-18", "30-Apr-18", "04-May-18"]
    })

res = (
    test_df
        .assign(
            # convert to datetime
            Dates = lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x.Dates),
            # get next rows date
            Dates_next = lambda x : x.Dates.shift(-1),
            # create the date range
            Dates_list = lambda x : x.apply(
                lambda x : 
                    pd.date_range(
                        x.Dates + timedelta(days=1), 
                        x.Dates_next - timedelta(days=1),
                        freq="D").date.tolist()
                    if pd.notnull(x.Dates_next)
                    else None
                , axis = 1
            ))
)
print(res)
```

results in:

```
        Dates Dates_next                                         Dates_list
0  2018-02-11 2018-02-18  [2018-02-12, 2018-02-13, 2018-02-14, 2018-02-1...
1  2018-02-18 2018-03-03  [2018-02-19, 2018-02-20, 2018-02-21, 2018-02-2...
2  2018-03-03 2018-03-25  [2018-03-04, 2018-03-05, 2018-03-06, 2018-03-0...
3  2018-03-25 2018-03-29               [2018-03-26, 2018-03-27, 2018-03-28]
4  2018-03-29 2018-04-04  [2018-03-30, 2018-03-31, 2018-04-01, 2018-04-0...
5  2018-04-04 2018-04-08               [2018-04-05, 2018-04-06, 2018-04-07]
6  2018-04-08 2018-04-14  [2018-04-09, 2018-04-10, 2018-04-11, 2018-04-1...
7  2018-04-14 2018-04-17                           [2018-04-15, 2018-04-16]
8  2018-04-17 2018-04-30  [2018-04-18, 2018-04-19, 2018-04-20, 2018-04-2...
9  2018-04-30 2018-05-04               [2018-05-01, 2018-05-02, 2018-05-03]
10 2018-05-04        NaT                                               None
```

As a sidenote, if you don't need the last row after the analysis, you could filter out the last row after assigning the next date and eliminate the `if` statement to make it faster.