# Batch File Downloader: Name Generator

Tags: python, batch-file

I am developing a program in python to download a list of files.
The are named as:

```
2012-01-01-01.html
2012-01-01-02.html
...
...
2012-12-30-99.html
```

The problem is I don't Know whether the file exists. So I have to check all the urls from 404
How can i make a generator that increments the counter for `'year'-'month'-'date'-'num` 
if one link fails then skip the date
and if all links of particular month fails skip month
and so on
I can only write code that is having lot of 'if's is there any better idea

```
wset_fail=[]
for year in [2012,2011]:
    for month in range(1,12):
        for day in range(1,31):
            for num in range(1,100):   
                check = str(year)+'-'+str(month)+'-'+str(day)
                if check not in wset_fail:
                    link = generate_name(year,month,day,num)
                    if link!='':
                        if download(link)==False:   
                            wset_fail.append(str(year)+'-'+str(month)+'-'+str(day))
```

Its Working I am asking for some better solution

Comment: a simple three nested for loops with a single if would work. Show us what you tried and why it failed.

Comment: You want `range(1, 13)` and `range(1, 32)`.  You also want to reuse `check` instead of recalculating `str(year)+…`. Furthermore, the test `check not in wset_fail` can be removed, since all `check` values are new, in the innermost loop.

Comment: check checks whether set of files for a particular file is already failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a separate generator for dates as described at  [Iterating through a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python). Then use the dates to download files.