# Iterate over days of a given month in django

Tags: django, loops

I'm using the generic `montharchiveview`, and at the template I can access to the month, the previous month, next month and my objects in the given month.

All I want to do is, to show all days in the given month and display the information about my objects of dat day. I would like to do something like that in my template:

```
{% for day in month %}
    {{day}}
{% endfor %}
```

And the result I want to get is something like:

```
JUNE

1
MyObject1
MyObject2

2
Nothing to show

3
MyObject3
MyObject4
MyObject5

4
Nothing to show

5
Nothing to show
...
```

How could I do this?

Comment: You should iterate over `date_list` instead of `month`.

Comment: No, because I want to show days without date, and days with more than one data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the first day of the next month and subtract one day from it to get the last day of the month. Then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python) with the first and the last days of the month.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't seen the link, I was writing from my phone. Your answer is looking good, but my real problem seems to be that I don't know how to share the variables between the template and view...

Comment: Same as always: pass it in the dictionary when rendering the template.

Comment: The problem is that is a generic view (montharchiveview) and in the views is defined as a class, and is not returning anything. So I don't know how to do that.