# python remove keys whose values add up to a total

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict1 = {datetime.timedelta(3, 21388, 702926): 2, datetime.timedelta(10, 21388, 702926): 1, datetime.timedelta(3, 65011, 297074): 2, datetime.timedelta(14, 65011, 297074): 1, datetime.timedelta(17, 65011, 297074): 1, datetime.timedelta(0, 65011, 297074): 1, datetime.timedelta(7, 65011, 297074): 1, datetime.timedelta(10, 65011, 297074): 1, datetime.timedelta(0, 21388, 702926): 1}
```

I am trying to remove the timedeltas, the sum of whose values equals 6. They also have to be the largest timedeltas in the dict.

Here's how I'm trying to solve it:

```
x = 0
for key in dict1:
    if key in sorted(dict1)[-1] and x < 6:
        x = x+dict1[key]
        del dict1[key]
```

My thinking is sorted(dict) returns a list of timedeltas with the largest ones at the end. I could match each key with the largest timedelta in the list, sum its value to x & remove that key until the x reaches 6. But this returns:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.timedelta' is not iterable
```

Stumped again.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a name, you are masking the built-in type.

Comment: Take a look at this question see if it helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Comment: What if the sum of the largest keys is *not* exactly 6?

Comment: What if the sum two non-consecutive values is 6 ? e.g. largest + smallest = 6

Comment: @MartijnPieters good question, I was thinking of handling that later. 6 here is arbitrary. Pick 5.

Comment: @SunnyNanda has to be the largest. the largest ones whose values add up to 6 need to go.

Comment: For the record, `sorted(dict1)` returns a list of (sorted) keys, so your `timedelta` objects. `[-1]` is the last one, the largest. You then try to use a membership test on that with `key in`. That's not working here. But your approach has bigger problems than that.

Comment: of course it does. Im not a programmer by trade :)

Comment: @koogee: look up "knapsack problem", you have one here.

Comment: if `dict1` have `6` elements all with value of `1` would you expect the answer to be empty `dict`?

Comment: You would like to find the keys which pair of values sums 6 ?

Comment: @podshumok In this particular case, dict1 will always have keys, the sum of whose values will be more than 6. Please use this as premise.

Comment: @tk not just keys whose values sum to 6, but the _largest_ keys whose values sum to 6.

Comment: @koogee ok, is there a limit on number of deletions from `dict1`?

Comment: @koogee but can you have more than 2 values in the sum ?

Comment: @podshumok how do you mean? the limit is the sum total 6. When sum of values of the largest keys approaches 6, the deletions should end.

Comment: @tk didnt quite understand that...? it doesnt matter if three values make up 6 or six values make up 6. Their corresponding keys must be the largest in the timedeltas.

Comment: @koogee suppose you have `3` big keys with values of `2` and `2` small keys with values of `3`. What you expect to be deleted?

Comment: @podshumok 3 big keys with values of 2. The keys have to be the largest.

Comment: @kogee and if you have one more, the biggest key with value of `1`?

Comment: @podshumok I get the problem you're pointing at. The sum of the largest keys may not always equal 6. I'm going to have to think of something to by pass that issue. But I think the gist of the original problem was figuring how to remove the largest keys based on sum of values.

Comment: @podshumok I should have set the sum to 4 for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I deduce that you want to delete the biggest timedeltas until the aggregated sum of their values reaches 6.

```
values_sum = 0
for key in sorted(dict1,reverse=True):
    values_sum +=dict1[key]
    del dict1[key]
    if values_sum >= 6:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked well for the problem presented. I'm going to test it a bit more and also look at the scenario when sum of the largest keys is not _exactly_ 6 like in this case.