# For loop with Python - using ints instead of datetime

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a datascience task that requires getting historical weather data. I have looked at wunderground.com but their API example is structured like so:

http://api.wunderground.com/api/d23ac65706dbf6dd/history_YYYYMMDD/q/CA/San_Francisco.json

Therefore, when attempting to build a dataset I need to get from the first day of the year to the last day of the year, but can't do that with:

```
    20140101
    20140102
    20140103
    ...
    20141229
    20141230
    20141231
```

The only thing that I can come up with is:

```
for m in range(1, 13):
    for d in range(1, 32):
         r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0def10027afaebb7/history_2014'+str(m)+'/'+str(d)+'/q/Mexico/Mexico_City.json")
        data = r.json()
```

But that obviously won't work. How would you go about this in Python?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1060279/3001761

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates how to iterate over actual dates:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start = datetime.date(2014, 1, 1)
>>> end = datetime.date(2014, 1, 5)
>>> while start <= end:
    print start.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    start += datetime.timedelta(days=1)


20140101
20140102
20140103
20140104
20140105
```

See [the `datetime` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for more information.

Comment: `print start.strftime('%Y%m%d')` and `start += datetime.timedelta(days=1)` are inner loop.

Comment: Awesome @jonrsharpe, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `calendar` module:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> cal = calendar.Calendar()
>>> year = 2014
>>> for month in range(1,13):
...    for day in cal.itermonthdates(year, month):
...        if day.year == year:
...           print day.strftime('%Y%m%d')
... 
20140101
20140102
20140103
20140104
...
...
20141229
20141230
20141231
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use datetime to convert int to datetime format and check whether the year matches your requirement.
for e.g

```
import datetime
s = 20140101
s_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(s), '%Y%m%d')
if s_datetime.year == 2014:
    //Do something
```