# Django date range to template issue

Tags: python, django, date, templates, range

I am trying to solve an issue with getting all dates within a range into my Django application template. I have a start date and an end date of a time sheet which are defined and I am able to pass them into the template. However, I want to fill in all of the dates in between into an HTML table but cannot seem to find a solution to this problem, as most solutions are for 1 date only. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

```
views.py

def time_page(request, result_name):
    records = TimeSheetMain.objects.get(timeSheet_code=result_name)
    empID = Employee.objects.get()
    req_user = request.user
    recordsUser = records.user
    if req_user == recordsUser:
        return render_to_response('ts.html',
                                  {'records': records, 'empID': empID},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

HTML Call:

```
Date Range: {{ records.startDate }} - {{ records.endDate }}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^ts/(.{36})', 'TimeSheetApp.views.time_page', name="time_page"),
```

Comment: I may not have it right, but you want to find all dates between two dates? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1060330/1753891

Answer (score 0):

1. In View:
   collect all dates into a list, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060330/1753891
2. In template:
   Use template forloop to populate the HTML table.

   ```
   {% for d in date_list %}
   {# table cell here #}
   {% endfor %}
   ```