# Looping through dates with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to loop through all the dates for the given time period with:

```
disp_start = dt.datetime(2017,1,6)           #####START DATE
disp_data = closingprices.loc[disp_start:]   #closing prices is data w/ stock prices  

for date in disp_data.index:
    returns = (closingprices.iloc[-1].divide(closingprices.iloc[date]))-1
```

But get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [2017-01-06 00:00:00] of <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Not sure how to loop through all periods from a given start date (disp_start). Thanks

Comment: do you need `loc` like `closingprices.loc[date]` ?

Comment: iloc is only for integer positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by label, because [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is for select by position(s):

```
for date in disp_data.index:
    returns = (closingprices.iloc[-1].divide(closingprices.loc[date]))-1
```

If need `iloc` for some reason is posssible use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
for date in disp_data.index:
    returns = (closingprices.iloc[-1].divide(closingprices.iloc[df.index.get_loc(date)]))-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
       yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2013, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2015, 6, 2)
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
print single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

[Iterating through a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python)