# Generate a sorted list of birthday dates and append each date to a newline in a file

Tags: python, list, generate, word-list

So, I have been trying to generate a wordlist with birthday dates. I am trying to append each value to a newline in a file birdthday_wordlist.txt. The file and the format should be like this:

```
01/01/1998
02/01/1998
03/01/1998
dd/mm/yyyy
12/12/2000
```

I was capable of generating only the dd, mm or yyyy, with scripts like this:

```
with open('XXXXXX_wordlist.txt', 'w') as birdthday_wordlist:
for i in range(1980, 2000):
    birdthday_wordlist.write('{}\n'.format(i))
```

I know there is a way, for now I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: If you need to loop through ranges in parallel, use `zip`, although this won't account for months with a different number of days

Comment: Apologies, I can't understand what you're asking. Where are you trying to sort values here?

Comment: Please add an example of the original file that you have, it's hard to understand what you are asking since you only showed the result file.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time, and I'm sorry if I couldn't make my question more clear. I just had an answer ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, it's very similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

I have adapted the answer to write the dates to a file:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(1980, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2000, 1, 1)
with open('XXXXXX_wordlist.txt', 'w+') as birdthday_wordlist:
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        birdthday_wordlist.write('%s\n' % single_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Will output:

```
01/01/1980
02/01/1980
03/01/1980
04/01/1980
05/01/1980
...
31/12/1999
```

Comment: Thank you man! It's just perfect and what I need. I do really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while and the datetime functions. You can set the ini date as you need, and the end date you want. It will sum 1 day each iteration

```
import datetime

ini=datetime.date(year=1980,month=1,day=1)
end=datetime.date(year=2000,month=1,day=1)
while ini<=end:
    birdthday_wordlist.write(ini.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')+'\n')
    ini=ini+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: And how is that sorted in any way?

Comment: I believe OP wants leading zeroes, i.e. 01/01/1980, 02/01/1980, etc.

Comment: Yeah, but you haven't actually sorted the list at all, and the question title asks for sorting.

Comment: With this format he would get leading zeros '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: I'm not talking about leading zeros, I'm talking about _sorting_ the data

Comment: @roganjosh No, he didn't say anything about sorting. He asked for a sorted list and that is what he gets. It is not the same to get a sorted list than to sort a list.

Comment: I honestly don't get the distinction, perhaps it's time for me to eat humble pie. Please explain what I'm not seeing.

Comment: @roganjosh It's easy. The list you get it is already sorted because you begin in the first day, and you add 1 day each time. So you get a sorted list and that is what he needs.

Comment: There is nothing in the question content that suggests this is sorted beforehand. The title of the question asked for "sorted" and we don't know how the data is generated.

Comment: The data is "sorted" by day, then month, then year. The data isn't being generated from an external source... it's just being created by the user and written to a file.

Comment: Yep, humble pie time :P

Comment: Mr. @nacho thank you for your time and contribution. The thing with your code is when I ran it, I had a 1.8 GB file with a couple of tens of millions of lines with the only value 01/01/1980 in all of that in every line...my computer's memory overflowed and I had to force quit everything and restart the machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution that doesn't use imported packages, you can do the following:

```
data = []
f_string = "%02d/%02d/%04d\n" # Will be presented as dd/mm/yyyy format

for year in range(1980, 2000):
    for month in range(1, 12):
        for day in range(1, 31):
            data.append(f_string % (day, month, year))

with open('XXXXXX_wordlist.txt', 'w') as birthday_wordlist:    
    for item in data:
        birthday_wordlist.write(item)
```

Comment: @musikrek much appreciated and thank you for your time and help. I just noticed that your code resulted in a Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 10, in <module>
    birthday_wordlist.write(data)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
So I just str(data) and It worked but I get many dates at one line in this format: '13/01/1980\n', '14/01/1980\n', '15/01/1980\n', '16/01/1980\n', '17/01/1980\n', '18/01/1980\n', ...

Comment: My apologies. The error was that I was writing the file, which makes no sense. Instead, I *should've* been writing the items in the `data` variable, as I am now doing.