# Time calculation and action grouping in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe has users, actions and the time users took the actions. I want to group actions into a list if they satisfy BOTH of the two conditions: 
*1. actions were taken by the same user 
2. actions were taken within 20 minutes.*

At the moment I'm trying to use timedelta to calculate time difference with iteration and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python) post but that's not what I'm looking for. I struggle to find similar examples.

the dataframe has thousands of rows, this is part of it

```
user    action      time
A       browse      2018-07-01 06:00:00
A       edit        2018-07-01 06:10:00
B       signin      2018-07-01 06:00:00
B       browse      2018-07-01 06:11:00
B       edit        2018-07-01 07:00:00
```

The expected output will be a list of the actions that satisfied the conditions

```
output
[[browse, edit], [signin, browse]]
```

The last 'edit' did by user B is not in it because (07:00:00) - (06:11:00) > 20 min

Any suggestions about how can I do this ? Thank you very much in advanced !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use,

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time) 

cond = df.groupby('user')['time'].diff().bfill().lt(pd.Timedelta('20m'))

df1 = df[cond].groupby('user')['action'].apply(list).tolist()

print (df1)

[['browse', 'edit'], ['signin', 'browse']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Just a quick question, is there anyway that I can randomly check are actions being allocated correctly? I tried `for i in df1:
    for j in i:
        if j == 'edit':
            print(i)`  but it print out the whole list   Thank you!

Comment: @Osca It's not clear what you want to check here. If you want to confirm then try it on a small subset of your data and verify.

Comment: Thanks but I want to return i (the list itself) if 'edit' was found. Like this: ['browse', 'edit']

Comment: @Osca You can use `for i in df1: if 'edit' in i: print(i)` This will return `['browse', 'edit']`

Comment: @Abhi, Would you be able to explain `.diff().bfill().` in the condition part , literal i know its `difference` and `backfill` but would like to know how its working here

Comment: @pygo Sure, when you take the `diff()` with `groupby` . The first row of every group will be `NaT` so `bfill` ensures that first row is also selected.