# How to represent the data in x and y axis using matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Here in my program i want to create the month wise dates on x axis label and and another rs data i want to represent on the y axis.can you please help me how to mention my data in matplotlib.

Given below is my sample program:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
# line 1 points
x1 = [1,2,3]
y1 = [2,4,1]
# plotting the line 1 points
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'g', label = "line 1",linewidth=10)
plt.title('Two lines on same graph!')
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True,color="k")
plt.show()
# xticks(np.arange(12), calendar.month_name[1:13], rotation=20)
```

i don't want to mention in between the values it is tacking the x and y values i want to mention like in given diagram.

[image]

Comment: So you want to plot date on x-axis, and make two line plots x1 and y1 to your graph?

Comment: yes dates on x axis and collection(same values i mentioned in diagram) amount i want to represent on y axis

Comment: Something like this: https://imgur.com/a/3jen76C ?

Comment: yes but i want to mention the display the all dates in month

Comment: can you please send  me that code

Comment: yes of course, just a second. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few edits and your comments. Is this more closer what you are looking for?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
# line 1 points
val = [1,2,3,2,6]
cust = [2,4,1,6,2]
orders = [3,5,2,7,3]
col = [1,3,4,2,6]
# plotting the line 1 points
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

start_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 07, 01)
dates = []

# Dates based on the measurement count
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python
for single_date in (start_date + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(len(val))):
    dates.append(single_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))


# Values
plt.plot(dates, val, '.',color='g', markersize=12)
plt.plot(dates, val, label='Values', color='g')

# Customers
plt.plot(dates, cust, '.',color='b', markersize=12)
plt.plot(dates, cust, label='Customers',color='b')

# Orders
plt.plot(dates, orders, '.',color='r', markersize=12)
plt.plot(dates, orders, label='Orders',color='r')

# Collection
plt.plot(dates, col, '.',color='black', markersize=12)
plt.plot(dates, col, label='Collection',color='black')

plt.title('Four lines on same graph!')
plt.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=20)
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
plt.grid(True,color="k")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: hi can i ask one more thing?

Comment: actually i want to mention my values in y axis and i want to draw four lines in plot one is for customers,orders,collection and something else..how can i plot ?

Comment: here in this example you took  list values

Comment: How different are these values? So is it wice to plot all of them to one graph? I would probably make 4 subplots if the y-axis values are different.

Comment: I modify the answer for 4 plots in one graph.

Comment: I added the x-axis dates to start from 1st of July and it is counting the month dates based on the length of your data.