# How to print the 'nth' value of For Loop output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, for-loop

So I was wondering if there is a way to print the nth value (not the last value) from a For Loop output. For eg: let's suppose I want to print just the 'fifth-to-last' value or just the 'third-to-last' value from the For Loop output. Any idea how can I do that? I am newbie at coding/python and I am building up this code after doing a lot of research & learning on the way. So any help appreciated.

Currently, the code below is giving me the last value.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int(start_date.day), int((end_date - start_date).days), 90):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2016, 1, 1)
end_date = date.today()
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    x = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print(x)
```

Comment: A problem with this code is it assumes (implicitly) that the iterator is non-empty. If the iterator happens to be empty it'll raise `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: Well, I got the code from this link here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python

I wasn't aware of this issue. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enumerate while looping which gives the iteration count. You can provide a condition inside based on the values you need to print as follows:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int(start_date.day), int((end_date - start_date).days), 90):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2016, 1, 1)
end_date = date.today()
n=5
length =len(list(daterange(start_date, end_date)))

for i,single_date in enumerate(daterange(start_date, end_date)):
    x = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    if i == length-n:
        print(x)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for just one specific value from the list and Raymond Hettinger solution gives me what I was looking for. Appreciate the help anyways. :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the question the previous time. I've updated my answer now. Let me know if this is what you expect.

Comment: if I have to automatically update the `n` value based on a condition how can I do that?

Comment: In that case, you can write it under a function and pass `n` as a parameter to it

Answer (score 3):

The technique is to accumulate the results in a container, and then print the n-th element back.

One possibility is to use [*collections.deque()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with a *maxlen* value set to *n*.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
from collections import deque

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int(start_date.day), int((end_date - start_date).days), 90):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

window = deque([], maxlen=5)
start_date = date(2016, 1, 1)
end_date = date.today()
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    x = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    window.append(x)

print(window[0])
```

The above code outputs the fifth oldest entry.

```
2018-12-17
```

The above code accumulates the most recent values in a sliding window of width *5*.  The oldest value in at position *0* and the newest value is at position *-1*.

You can change the *5* to be any value of *n* that you need.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot. :) I would never have been able to guess this. Also, I learned about something new as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: This might be quite memory-consiming if you're looking for nth element for large `n`. I think Raghul Raj's solution is better for general case.

Comment: The OP listed examples of 3rd to last or 5th to last.  There was no mention of hundreds of thousands or millions that would consume much memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing to only get certain elements by index.
Slicing does not work on generators however, so you will need to cast to a list.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int(start_date.day), int((end_date - start_date).days), 90):
       yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2016, 1, 1)
end_date = date.today()
for single_date in list(daterange(start_date, end_date))[4:]:
    x = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print(x)
```

This will print the 5th (index: 4) to last element.