# Iterating between time range

Tags: python, loops

I would need to run the code iterating the scraping in a date range. 
Currently I am doing it manually as follows:

```
start_date=input("Enter start date: mm/dd/yyyy ") 
end_date=input("Enter end date: mm/dd/yyyy ") 
query=input("Enter query: ")
print("\n")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path')
driver.get('path’+‘cd_min=start_date&cd_max=end_date’)
```

The link above might be slightly different.
I would like to insert the start date manuanlly, then iterate with a while or for loop the functions through time, at step of 1 `(start_date+1, start_date+2, and so on)` from a  `start_date` to an `end_date` chosen at the beginning using input as well).

Could you please tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you need to create a range of dates that you can iterate over. 
That could be accomplished by this using pandas. Assuming your input is correct you could do the following.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_date=input("Enter start date: mm/dd/yyyy ") 
end_date=input("Enter end date: mm/dd/yyyy ") 

datelist = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date).to_pydatetime().tolist()
for i, _ in enumerate(datelist):
    if i <len(datelist):
        start_date = datelist[i].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        end_date = datelist[i+1].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path')
        driver.get('path'+f'cd_min={start_date}&cd_max={end_date}')
```