# pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data with data which made no mistake before

Tags: python, pandas, tokenize

I am trying to solve `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data` problem.

I have two types of data.

I use a same code but it does not work with a type of data as I attach below. (It works well with another)

```
(msnoise) [sujan@node01 MSNoise_test2]$ msnoise plot dvv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/bin/msnoise", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msnoise/scripts/msnoise.py", line 1202, in run
    cli(obj={})
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msnoise/scripts/msnoise.py", line 943, in dvv
    main(mov_stack, dttname, comp, filterid, pair, all, show, outfile)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msnoise/plots/dvv.py", line 89, in main
    df = pd.read_csv(day,sep=",", header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
  File "/home/sujan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 709, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/sujan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 455, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/home/sujan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1069, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/home/sujan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1839, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 902, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 924, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 978, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 965, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2208, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 114, saw 15
```

I add `, error_bad_lines=False` but it does not help and shows error as below.

```
(msnoise) [sujan@node01 MSNoise_test2]$ msnoise plot dvv
Skipping line 114: expected 8 fields, saw 15

(1,                             A        EA        EM       EM0         M  \
Date
2013-09-29 00:00:00 -0.076348       inf       inf  0.000501 -0.002737
2013-09-29 00:00:00  0.014844  0.021573  0.001400  0.001239  0.000257
2013-09-29 00:00:00 -0.071597  0.002802  0.000144  0.001724 -0.000043
2013-09-29 00:00:00 -0.047929       inf       inf  0.002285  0.001605
2013-09-29 00:00:00 -0.135391       inf       inf  0.002244  0.011393

                           M0            Pairs
Date
2013-09-29 00:00:00  0.000836  05_TP01_05_TP10
2013-09-29 00:00:00  0.000558  05_TP02_05_TP10
2013-09-29 00:00:00  0.002713  05_TP09_05_TP10
2013-09-29 00:00:00  0.008074  05_TP01_05_TP09
2013-09-29 00:00:00  0.000346  05_TP02_05_TP09  )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/bin/msnoise", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msnoise/scripts/msnoise.py", line 1202, in run
    cli(obj={})
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msnoise/scripts/msnoise.py", line 943, in dvv
    main(mov_stack, dttname, comp, filterid, pair, all, show, outfile)
  File "/home/sujan/anaconda3/envs/msnoise/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msnoise/plots/dvv.py", line 140, in main
    tmp2 = allbut[dttname].resample('D').mean()
  File "/home/sujan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5522, in resample
    base=base, key=on, level=level)
  File "/home/sujan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 999, in resample
    return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "/home/sujan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1096, in _get_resampler
    self._set_grouper(obj)
  File "/home/sujan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 439, in _set_grouper
    indexer = self.indexer = ax.argsort(kind='mergesort')
  File "/home/sujan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2151, in argsort
    return result.argsort(*args, **kwargs)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 1165, in pandas._libs.tslib._Timestamp.__richcmp__
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'
```

However, the data with problem worked well until two weeks ago but suddenly shows the parsererror.

I even did not touch any data or results.

Additionally, the code that makes problems I think is like below.

```
   for i, mov_stack in enumerate(mov_stacks):
        current = start
        first = True
        alldf = []
        while current <= end:
            for comp in components:
                day = os.path.join('DTT', "%02i" % filterid, "%03i_DAYS" % mov_stack, comp, '%s.txt' % current)
                if os.path.isfile(day):
                    df = pd.read_csv(day, header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
                    alldf.append(df)
            current += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        if len(alldf) == 0:
            print("No Data for %s m%i f%i" % (components, mov_stack, filterid))
            continue
```

the code  `day = os.path.join('DTT', "%02i" % filterid, "%03i_DAYS" % mov_stack, comp, '%s.txt' % current)` reads txt file like below.

```
Date,A,EA,EM,EM0,M,M0,Pairs
2014-05-10,0.419549372718,inf,inf,0.000458496085412,-0.0160997929491,0.000732900920237,05_SS08_05_TP01
2014-05-10,-0.0429633365955,inf,inf,0.000525405329004,0.000306985380522,0.00237631297525,05_TP01_05_TP07
2014-05-10,0.067236405269,inf,inf,0.00256763292024,-0.000489522024887,0.000310750516333,05_SS08_05_TP10
2014-05-10,-0.0286482054004,inf,inf,0.00101017717763,-0.00188012718704,-0.00148293566406,05_SS02_05_SS05
```

But the data without problem has the same txt file format and there's no problem. So weird.

It makes my work all stopped.. So if you know what I have to do or need other information to solve this, please let me know.

Comment: Is it literally the same data (exactly the same file), or is it the same *type* of data? Try opening the file in Excel and looking at Line 114 (does it have 15 items?). Are `start` and `end` both datetime objects? If you comment out the code that you think is causing the error, does the error go away (or change into a different error?) And this might not be related to the error, but you might want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Comment: If you mean the another data, it is different data but same type of data (cause different study area).  Both start and end are datetime objects. And the code that I think causing the error is main point of the code, so I cannot delete. I will see the link you give. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. The reason was the environment variable. I add python path there for solving `no module` problem which occurred before `parsererror`. But it was not the solution for the `no module` problem but to edit bashrc. Anyway, when I delete the python path in the environment variable and do all the steps (cc, mwcs etc), `msnoise plot dvv` finally works so well.