# How can I show dates between two years with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Actually i want to show dates between two dates in diferent years, the dates are start_ts = 2021/11/02 and end_ts = 2022/03/02 I expect the results shows starts 2021/11/02, 2021/12/02, 2022/01/02, 2022/02/02 and the ends = 2021/12/02, 2021/01/02, 2022/02/02, 2022/03/02

I try with that code but i can't make the result shows the result that i want

```
start_ts, end_ts = Timestamp(self.date_from), Timestamp(self.date_to)
starts = bdate_range(start_ts, end_ts, freq='M') + Day(-int(dias))
ends = date_range(start_ts + MonthEnd(2), end_ts, freq='M') + Day(-int(diasx-1))
```

Comment: What library is `MonthEnd` and `Date` from?

Comment: This any help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Comment: @user17242583: `from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd, Day`

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you.