# Python: iterate per year between two dates

Tags: python

I'm not a Python developer but have to fix an existing code.

In this code, a method (`extract`) is called providing an interval of dates:

`extract(start_date, end_date)`

The parameters can have for exemple the values:

```
start_date : 2020-10-01
end_date   : 2022-01-03
```

**The problem**

The issue with this call is that the `extract` method only support a 1 year max interval of dates. If greater, the interval must be split, for exemple as follow:

```
extract('2020-10-01', '2020-12-31')
extract('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')
extract('2022-01-01', '2022-01-03')
```

So I'm trying to create loop where the start_date and end_date are computed dynamically. But being new to Python, I have no ideas for now how this can be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Answer to some comments here
Tried so far finding a solution starting from code like this so far:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

from_date = datetime.strptime('2020-10-01', "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date  = datetime.strptime('2022-01-03', "%Y-%m-%d")

# Get the interval between the two dates
diff = relativedelta.relativedelta(end_date, from_date)
```

Then I thought iterating accross the years using `diff.years` and adding some logic to build the start_date and end_date from there, but I thought there might be a much simplier approach.

Also saw others possibilities like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python) but still no final simple result found at the moment.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Since your inputs are strings, given a specific format you can parse them and obtain values for year from there, then convert it to numbers to increment while calling the `extract` function. Show us something you tried and why it didn't work. Expected result and current result is very helpful in these situations

Comment: Use the datetime library of python to perform operations with dates

Comment: what do you need to be returned for the two dates in the example?

Comment: @Jayvee the extract method is just returning a "returncode" (success=0 or failed=-1) after the processing. What does the extract method have no impact of the solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from_str = '2020-10-01'
end_str = '2022-01-03'

from_year = int(from_str[:4])
end_year = int(end_str[:4])

if from_year != end_year:
    # from_date to end of first year
    extract(from_str, f"{from_year}-12-31")

    # full years
    for y in range(from_year + 1, end_year):
        extract(f"{y}-01-01", f"{y}-12-31")

    # rest
    extract(f"{end_year}-01-01", end_str)
else:
    extract(from_str, end_str)
```

Comment: Sounds simple and interesting. Just guessing it will fails if there is a 1 year only interval between the 2 dates. For e.g. with `from_str = '2021-10-01'` and `end_str = '2022-01-03'` as it in the call: `extract(f"{y}-01-01", f"{y}-12-31")` the end_date will be 2022-12-31 instead of '2022-01-03', but got the idea. Many thanks !

Comment: @HeyStackExchange you can write a dummy extract function like `def extract(s1, s2): print(s1, s2)` and test it yourself. It works for `from_str = '2021-10-01'` and `end_str = '2022-01-03'`. The full year loop isn't entered in this case.

Comment: Apologizes if so. Will try and come back for the results. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can either use the datetime library or you can also use pandas if you want. The pandas version is the following (admittively not the most pretty, but it does the job):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2020,10,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2022,1,3)


def extract(from_dt, to_dt):
    print(f'Extracting from {from_dt} to {to_dt}')


prev_end = pd.to_datetime(start)
for next_end in pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(start.year, 12, 31), end, freq='y'):
    if next_end < end:
        extract(prev_end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), next_end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    else:
        extract(prev_end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    prev_end = next_end + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
if prev_end < end:
    extract(prev_end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

If you need to parse the original dates from strings, check out [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: That's sounds interesting. I'll try and come back for the result. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problems are nice ones to resolve by recursion:

```
   from datetime import datetime
    
    start_date = '2020-10-01'
    end_date   = '2022-01-03'
    
    def intervalcalc(datestart,dateend):
        newdate=dateend[:4] + '-01-01'
        startd = datetime.strptime(datestart, "%Y-%m-%d")
        endd =   datetime.strptime(newdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
        if endd < startd:
            print(datestart, dateend)
            return True
        else:
            print(newdate, dateend)
            previousyear=str(int(newdate[:4])-1) + '-12-31'
            intervalcalc(datestart,previousyear)
    
    
    intervalcalc(start_date, end_date)
```

output:

```
2022-01-01 2022-01-03
2021-01-01 2021-12-31
2020-10-01 2020-12-31
```

You just need to change the prints by calls to extract function.

As mentioned by @Wups the conversion to date is not really necessary, it could be an string compare as they are YYYYMMDD dates.

Also, this can be done the other way around and calculate from the start date year + '-12-31' and then compare dateend>end_date to determine the anchor for the recursion.

Comment: put the second `print` below the recursive `intervalcalc` call to get the correct output order.

Comment: I think, you don't even need `datetime` for your solution. The date strings will compare correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Wups , you are right , the conversion to date it's an overkilling.

Comment: @Jayvee Thanks for the concise code you get with recursivity. Will check too

Comment: @Jayvee It's working. Marked the answer of Wups as "answered" as simple to understand.  Still, up voted your solution, which is the most elegant and concise. Many thanks!