# Python API Call Loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to call an api endpoint and return the data to a json file but the api endpoint is limited to only date ranges of 30 days per call. I want to hit the api, call the first date range output the data to the json file, call the api endpoint again and append the new data to the json file.

How can I do this? I've got code to hit the api endpoint and return the data but haven't been able to figure out how to get further.

Example date: `dateFrom=2022-01-01&dateTo=2022-01-29`, next would be `dateFrom=2022-02-01&dateTo=2022-02-29`, etc.

```
import requests

url = "https://apiendpoint.com/v2/dapps/xxxx/history/uaw?dateFrom=2022-01-01&dateTo=2022-01-29"

headers = {
 "accept": 'application/json',
 "x-api-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

i think i figured it out:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Function to get data from API for a given date range
def get_data(date_from, date_to):
    url = "https://apiendpoint.com/v2/dapps/xxxxx/history/uaw?dateFrom={date_from}&dateTo={date_to}"
    headers = {
        "accept": 'application/json',
        "x-api-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response.text

# Function to save data to a file
def save_to_file(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'a') as file:
        file.write(data + '\n')

# Start and end dates
start_date = datetime(2022, 1, 2)
end_date = datetime(2024, 3, 22)

# Loop through date ranges
while start_date < end_date:
    date_from = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    date_to = (start_date + timedelta(days=30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    
    # Get data for this 30-day range
    data = get_data(date_from, date_to)
    
    # Save data to file
    save_to_file(data, 'output.txt')
    
    # Move to next 30-day range
    start_date += timedelta(days=30)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to write a loop in general?

Comment: more-so, how do i have it loop through date ranges in the dateFrom & dateTo fields starting at 2022-01-01 - 2024-03-22 and output and append the results to a file