Python Code for downloading several files with similar names
I am trying to download CSV files from this website:
https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/real-time--market-data/market-reports#nt=%2FMarketReportType%3AHistorical%20LMP%2FMarketReportName%3ADay-Ahead%20Market%20ExPost%20LMPs%20(csv)&t=10&p=0&s=MarketReportPublished&sd=desc
and I want to download all the files from 2022/01/01, which is on the last page, all the way to the newest file, which comes out daily.  From this screenshot of the website, it's evident that there is a pattern to the naming of the files, such that all files include the year, month, and day (e.g. 20240525) and all end in _da_expost_lmp.csv.
Therefore, how could I write a Python code to download these files from the earliest date in that section to the most recent one updated daily? I understand that possibly I may need to use a loop of some kind, but any clarification would be useful as I am new to Python and don't want to  resort to ChatGPT for learning purposes.
This is my existing code:
import urllib3     
import pandas as pd     

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)     

df = pd.read_csv('https://docs.misoenergy.org/marketreports/20240524_da_expost_lmp.csv', skiprows = 4)     
df.head()  

How could I update this to my request? Any help would be appreciated; thank you.

if you know pattern then use for-loop to run read_csv with different names.

For downloading these files I would indeed use a for-loop. But first a few libraries have to be imported:
import pandas as pd
import urllib3
from datetime import date, timedelta,datetime

then I would define start dates (a part of this code also comes from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060330/18192272):
start_date = date(2022, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2024, 5, 27)

Because I cannot open the website with the csv files to check everything, I will just leave the next line of code you used:
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

Now a function is specified to iterate over all the dates between the start_date and the end_date:
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

And lastly a for loop which puts all the parts together and where the csv files can be opened. A string is made for every date, otherwise it cannot be used in the string.format():
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    date_str = single_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    print('https://docs.misoenergy.org/marketreports/{}_da_expost_lmp.csv'.format(date_str))
    #df = pd.read_csv('https://docs.misoenergy.org/marketreports/{}_da_expost_lmp.csv'.format(date_str))
    #df.head()

Alternatively, the name of the file can be made in another line of code, that would look like this:
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    date_str = single_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    filename = 'https://docs.misoenergy.org/marketreports/{}_da_expost_lmp.csv'.format(date_str)
    print(filename)
    #df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    #df.head()

In this loop the names of the file are just printed, but when the '#' is removed the csv files should be read out and the top rows will be shown.
Hopefully this helps!
