# Python function for flexibly creating datetime range

Tags: python, datetime, range

I am trying to write a function that can flexibly create consecutive datetime objects similarly to the standard `range()` function or the numpy `linspace()` function.
The function should be able to accept either a `num` argument or a `step` size argument to determine the sequence. Moreover, there should be options to include or exclude both the startpoint and the endpoint.
Thus, the signature of the function should be like this:

```py
import datetime as dt
def datetime_range(start: dt.datetime, stop: dt.datetime, step: dt.timedelta = None, num: int = None, startpoint=True, endpoint=True)
```

Desired outputs should look something like this:

```py
start = dt.datetime.min
stop = start + dt.timedelta(days=1)
num = 4

>>> datetime_range(start, end, num=num, startpoint=True, endpoint=True)
>>> [datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 2, 0, 0)]

>>> datetime_range(start, end, num=num, startpoint=False, endpoint=True)
>>> [datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 2, 0, 0)]

>>> datetime_range(start, end, num=num, startpoint=True, endpoint=False)
>>> [datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 18, 0)]

>>> datetime_range(start, end, num=num, startpoint=False, endpoint=False)
>>> [datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 4, 48), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 9, 36), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 14, 24), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 19, 12)]
```

What I have come up with so far is below. But it is not working as intended and I got stuck.

```
def datetime_range(start: dt.datetime, stop: dt.datetime, step: dt.timedelta = None, num: int = None, startpoint=True,endpoint=True):

    assert bool(step) != bool(num), f'only one of step or num must be given'
    delta = stop - start
    if bool(num):
        if endpoint and startpoint:
            div = num - 1
        elif endpoint != startpoint:
            div = num
        else:
            div = num + 1
        step = delta / div
    else:
        if endpoint and startpoint:
            div = delta / step
        elif endpoint != startpoint:
            div = (end - step) / step  # or (delta / step) - 1
        else:
            div = (end - 2 * step) / step  # or (delta/step) -2

    return ((start + (not startpoint) * step) + x * step for x in range(div))
```

I am working in Python 3.8. Maybe someone can give me hint. Also, I have a suspicion that there might be a more elegant way of computing the `div` than using `if, elif, else`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the algorithm used?

Comment: Check this out, i'm fairly sure it does everything you need. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html

Comment: And this is a partial duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868130/generating-all-dates-within-a-given-range-in-python/5868214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrections to your code:

- When using `num`, it is mandatory that the returned items must be of length `num` e.g. if `num=4` then it is expected that the resulting list contains 4 datetimes. So `.. for x in range(div)` is incorrect because `div` might be `+- num` thus the main reason why your code returns only 3 items when 4 is expected.
- When using `step`, we shouldn't worry about the total number of iterations as the incremented `step` is fixed. The only thing we need to do is count those increments as the basis of the `range` while taking into account if the `startpoint` and `endpoint` are included or not.
- You should validate the inputs further to ensure that `step` or `num` isn't 0 to make sure that we are moving forward to the `stop` count and not stuck to the same point due to incrementing just 0.
- It would be better to adjust `start` outside the generator. It is more straight-forward that way.
- The conditions used such as `bool(num)` is not necessary. We can just directly check `num` after the validations we made.

```
import datetime as dt


def datetime_range(start: dt.datetime, stop: dt.datetime, step: dt.timedelta = None, num: int = None, startpoint=True,endpoint=True):
    assert None in (step, num), f'only one of step or num must be given'
    if step is not None:
        assert step.total_seconds() > 0, f"Step shouldn't be 0"
    if num is not None:
        assert num > 0, f"Num shouldn't be 0"

    delta = stop - start

    if num:
        if endpoint and startpoint:
            div = num - 1
        elif endpoint or startpoint:
            div = num
        else:
            div = num + 1
        step = delta / div
    else:
        num = delta // step
        if endpoint and startpoint:
            num += 1
        elif endpoint or startpoint:
            pass
        else:
            num -= 1

    if not startpoint:
        start += step

    return (start + (x * step) for x in range(num))


start = dt.datetime.min
stop = start + dt.timedelta(days=1)
num = 4
step = dt.timedelta(hours=4)

print(f"Using num {num}")
print(list(datetime_range(start, stop, num=num, startpoint=True, endpoint=True)))
print(list(datetime_range(start, stop, num=num, startpoint=False, endpoint=True)))
print(list(datetime_range(start, stop, num=num, startpoint=True, endpoint=False)))
print(list(datetime_range(start, stop, num=num, startpoint=False, endpoint=False)))

print(f"\nUsing step {step}")
print(list(datetime_range(start, stop, step=step, startpoint=True, endpoint=True)))
print(list(datetime_range(start, stop, step=step, startpoint=False, endpoint=True)))
print(list(datetime_range(start, stop, step=step, startpoint=True, endpoint=False)))
print(list(datetime_range(start, stop, step=step, startpoint=False, endpoint=False)))
```

**Output**

```
Using num 4
[datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 2, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 2, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 18, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 4, 48), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 9, 36), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 14, 24), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 19, 12)]

Using step 4:00:00
[datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 20, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 2, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 20, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 2, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 20, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 20, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! With your answer I was able to see the blatant mistakes I made!