# How can I make a python numpy arange of datetime

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, timedelta

I have some input data, with timestamps in the input file in the form of hours from the date time specified in the filename.

This is a bit useless, so I need to convert it to python datetime.datetime objects, and then put it in a numpy array.  I could write a for loop, but I'd like to do something like:

```
numpy.arange(datetime.datetime(2000, 1,1), datetime.datetime(2000, 1,2), datetime.timedelta(hours=1))
```

which throws a TypeError.

Can this be done?  I'm stuck with python 2.6 and numpy 1.6.1.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See [NumPy Datetimes and Timedeltas](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html). Since NumPy 1.7, you can represent datetimes in NumPy using the `numpy.datetime64` type, which permits you to do ranges of values:

```py
>>> np.arange(np.datetime64("2000-01-01"), np.datetime64("2000-01-02"), np.timedelta64(1, "h"))
array(['2000-01-01T00', '2000-01-01T01', '2000-01-01T02', '2000-01-01T03',
       '2000-01-01T04', '2000-01-01T05', '2000-01-01T06', '2000-01-01T07',
       '2000-01-01T08', '2000-01-01T09', '2000-01-01T10', '2000-01-01T11',
       '2000-01-01T12', '2000-01-01T13', '2000-01-01T14', '2000-01-01T15',
       '2000-01-01T16', '2000-01-01T17', '2000-01-01T18', '2000-01-01T19',
       '2000-01-01T20', '2000-01-01T21', '2000-01-01T22', '2000-01-01T23'],
      dtype='datetime64[h]')
```

For NumPy 1.6, which has a much less useful `datetime64` type, you can use a suitable list comprehension to build the datetimes (see also [Creating a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python)):

```
base = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
arr = numpy.array([base + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in xrange(24)])
```

This produces

```
array([2000-01-01 00:00:00, 2000-01-01 01:00:00, 2000-01-01 02:00:00,
   2000-01-01 03:00:00, 2000-01-01 04:00:00, 2000-01-01 05:00:00,
   2000-01-01 06:00:00, 2000-01-01 07:00:00, 2000-01-01 08:00:00,
   2000-01-01 09:00:00, 2000-01-01 10:00:00, 2000-01-01 11:00:00,
   2000-01-01 12:00:00, 2000-01-01 13:00:00, 2000-01-01 14:00:00,
   2000-01-01 15:00:00, 2000-01-01 16:00:00, 2000-01-01 17:00:00,
   2000-01-01 18:00:00, 2000-01-01 19:00:00, 2000-01-01 20:00:00,
   2000-01-01 21:00:00, 2000-01-01 22:00:00, 2000-01-01 23:00:00], dtype=object)
```

Comment: If only I had numpy 1.7, this would be the answer.  But it seems I have 1.6.1, so the example doesn't work.

Comment: And is also compatible with the datetime I need to output.  Thanks!

Comment: this is not a vectorized solution, so may be slow

Answer (score 56):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

t = np.arange(datetime(1985,7,1), datetime(2015,7,1), timedelta(days=1)).astype(datetime)
```

The key point here is to use `astype(datetime)`, otherwise the result will be `datetime64`.

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. Any idea? what to import first?

Comment: @weefwefwqg3 Your import is probably `import datetime` instead of `from datetime import datetime`, so `datetime` is not the class but the module itself.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that `object` arrays will be quite a bit slower than `datetime64` arrays for most operations; you should probably prefer `datetime64` arrays over `object` (`datetime.datetime`) arrays, at least for NumPy 1.7+.

Answer (score 24):

With modern NumPy you can do this:

```
np.arange(np.datetime64('2017-01-01'), np.datetime64('2017-01-08'))
```

And it gives you:

```
array(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04',
       '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Comment: Can I put step here? like: a week, 10 days, a month, or a year?

Comment: @weefwefwqg3: Sure.  Use `np.timedelta64(...)`.

Answer (score 10):

As noted in another answer, for Numpy > 1.7, you can use Numpy's built-in datetime capability. The examples in the Numpy documentation don't include using `np.arange` with steps, so here's one:

`timearray = np.arange('2000-01-01', '2000-01-02',np.timedelta64(1,'h'), dtype='datetime64')`

Numpy sets the dtype of this result to `datetime64[h]`. You can set this explicitly to some smaller unit of time with `dtype='datetime64[m]'`.

In version 1.8.1 (and I expect earlier), trying to add an offset to that result array that is smaller than an hour will have no effect.

- `timearray += np.timedelta64(10,'s')` does not change `timearray`
- `timearray2 = timearray + np.timedelta64(10,'s')` will add 10 seconds to `timearray` and converts the dtype of `timearray2` to `datetime64[s]`

Answer (score 9):

Note that @nneonneo solution can be simplified in

```
result = first_date + np.arange(24) * datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

thanks to NumPy array manipulations. The `result` array has then a `dtype=object`.

For more complex ranges, you might be interested in the [`scikits.timeseries`](http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/) package (no longer maintained) or better, the 
 [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package that reimplemented most of the ideas of `scikits.timeseries`. Both packages support older versions of NumPy (1.5, 1.6...)

Comment: Thanks - it looks like I should have been using pandas for the entire task.  Next time :-)