# How to make a numpy arange of datetime without a specific year?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I have data of days from all days from *2004-01-01* until *2015-31-12* and want to plot the maximum and the minimun value of each day. 
The original data is on `df` and `df['Day']` is a colum with day and month.

So, I created two new dataframes:

```
dfmin=df.groupby('Day').agg('min')
dfmax=df.groupby('Day').agg('max')
```

The new dataframes has one row for each day of the year, considering the max and the minimun value for each day in the range.

I want to label the axis with each day, but without specify any year.
I already saw [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137277/how-can-i-make-a-python-numpy-arange-of-datetime) and [this documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) but did not find the answer.

For example, I did:

```
observation_dates = np.arange('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')
plt.plot(dfmin.index, dfmin.Data_Value)
plt.plot(dfmin.index, dfmax.Data_Value)
...
```

And created the following chart:
[image]

But I would like to do something like:

```
observation_dates = np.arange(' -01-01', ' -01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')
...
```

So the axis would be labeled just with the days, but without specifying any year

**EDIT TO CLARIFY A LITTLE MORE:**

After group the data by days, I got the following dataframe (represented by the blue line at the chart):

```
DAY     Data_Value
01-01    -160
01-02    -267
01-03    -267
```

I just want to plot this values using dates at x-axis

Comment: So are you only talking about the way the labels are displayed or do you want to actually group the data by month and day?

Comment: I already grouped the data by month and day, I just want to create an arange to label the chart

Comment: It's not obvious why you need that. If you decided that your plot has the dates from 2013, you can use 2013 in the `arange`.

Comment: I edited the question, explaining better what I need

Comment: I think there is a misconception. Datetimes cannot exist without date. But what you want is to only use the month for labelling, that is, you need a tick at a specific date, 2013-01-01, but that tick's label can be anything, even `"My daughter's birthday"`. Labelling is steered via `Formatters` in matplotlib. So you can use a `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter()`.

Comment: You are wright, I just wnat to label in month-day format. I edited the question. I read the documentation but did not find a way