# How to Convert a List to numpy.datetime64 format

Tags: python, numpy, datetime64

I know that we can create a single string to `np.datetime64` format such as:

```
a = np.datetime64('2020-01-01')
```

But what if we have a list with multiple strings of dates in it?

How are we able to apply the same `np.datetime64` to convert all the elements inside into a datetime format? Apart from doing a for-loop perhaps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a python numpy arange of datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137277/how-can-i-make-a-python-numpy-arange-of-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
strings_list= [...]
npdate_list = [np.datetime64(x) for x in strings_list]
```

Is there a specific reason for you to want to avoid a loop?

List comprehension is okay?

Comment: OP is looking for solution without loops.

Comment: Yes, I read that. Waiting to see why he wants to avoid a loop to see how we can help.

Comment: Because I am not a seasoned programmer, I am very new to it as I need to learn as a side course so Python is the only language I know so I try to avoid loops if I can because we may convert that single string easily to np.datetime64 but when we have a list then it is different. Maybe you could show me a simplified for-loop :) ? Thanks buddy !

Comment: My first answer is a loop ! It is called list comprehension and it creates a list from the "internal" for loop. But you are right, that will come later if you are new.

For the simple for loop:

    lst = ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-05', '2020-03-07' ]
    date_list = []
    for element in lst:
        date_list.append(np.datetime64(element))

Answer (score 2):

When you have your string list, use it as a source to a *Numpy* array,
passing *datetime64* as *dtype*. E.g.:

```
lst = ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-05', '2020-03-07' ]
a = np.array(lst, dtype='datetime64')
```

When you execute `a` (actually print this array in a notebook),
you will get:

```
array(['2020-01-01', '2020-02-05', '2020-03-07'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

As you can see, in this case the default precision is *Day*.
But you can pass the precision explicitely, e.g. `b = np.array(lst, dtype='datetime64[s]')`.

Don't be misled by apostrophes surrounding each element in the above
printout, they are **not** strings. To check it, execute `a[0]` and
you will get:

```
numpy.datetime64('2020-01-01')
```

Comment: Hmm I am not very sure what do you mean about the precision, I ran the code

a = np.array(lst, dtype='datetime64')

and printed out each element type() and it gave me datetime64 indeed.

Comment: Date precision can be e.g. "Day", but only in *Numpy*. *Pandas* uses *ms* (miliseconds) precision.

Comment: Meaning in Numpy I am unable to print the seconds out ? Day is the most precised dimension ?

Comment: How will the format be like for each string: 'YYYY-MM-DD' that is all I know hehe

Comment: Create *Numpy* arrays of *datetime* type, but with different precision and then print values. E.g. for *Day* precision you can have values only at 0:00 hrs in various days.

Comment: Hmm gotcha. But let's say if I want to just convert a string with just Y-M-D precision and I just pass the list into the array function including 'dtype = datetime64', I will successfully converted each element in the array to datetime64 yep?