# Creating a loop for two dates

Tags: python, date, for-loop, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterating through a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

I have two entries:

```
date1 = 2004.09.25
date2 = 2004.10.08
```

I want to wrote a script in Python that recognizes the date range and print them. something like this:

```
for i in range(date1:date2):
    print i
```

Do I need to define the dates in a particular format for dates?
The expected output is like:

```
2004.09.25
2004.09.26
.
.
.
2004.10.08
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Comment: This is an exact dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python (and morphyn's linked question is very close to the same thing).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your first step should have been to look at the python datetime library.

Overall, your first solution could look something like this:

```
date1 = datetime.date(2004, 9, 25)
date2 = datetime.date(2004, 10, 8)
day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

while date1 <= date2:
    print date1.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
    date1 = date1 + day
```

(one thing to note: this will obviously clobber your `date1` variable)

I would later refactor this into a daterange function so that you can do something closer to what you did; it would look like

```
for d in daterange(date1, date2):
    print d.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
```

Later on, when you develop your python skills, it could like like this:

```
for i in range((date2 - date1).days + 1):
    print (date1 + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
```

Or this, which would be my final version:

```
def daterange(d1, d2):
    return (d1 + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range((d2 - d1).days + 1))

for d in daterange(date1, date2):
    print d.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Insightful indeed

Answer (score 3):

Use the builtin [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module.

Firstly, split your dates (assuming it is a string) by each `.` and pass the lists to `datetime.date`

```
date1 = datetime.date(*date1.split('.'))
date2 = datetime.date(*date2.split('.'))
```

Then get the `ordinal` of each of the dates (number of days since Jan 1 0001)

```
date1 = date1.toordinal()
date2 = date2.toordinal()
```

Then, use a `for` loop, and the `fromordinal` function to convert an ordinal to a date

```
for i in range(date1, date2 + 1):
    print date.fromordinal(i).strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
```

Putting it all together:

```
date1 = datetime.date(*date1.split('.')).toordinal()
date2 = datetime.date(*date2.split('.')).toordinal()
for i in range(date1, date2 + 1):
    print date.fromordinal(i).strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
```

Answer (score 2):

using the ordinal functions it would go something like this:

```
import datetime

DATE1 = datetime.date(2004,9,25)
DATE2 = datetime.date(2004,10,8)
D1 = datetime.date.toordinal(DATE1)
D2 = (datetime.date.toordinal(DATE2))+1


for i in range(D1,D2):
    print datetime.date.fromordinal(i)
```