# Get dates as array

Tags: python, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterating through a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

I got a method where I pass in a start date and an end date. the end result is I want all the dates between the start date and end date as a list. For eg if the start date is '2013-01-01' and the end date is '2013-01-04' then ['2013-01-01','2013-01-02','2013-01-03','2013-01-04'] should be returned. I could do something like the below. But wondered if there a simple way I havent considered

```
year = int(startdate.split('-')[0])
month = int(startdate.split('-')[1])
day = int(startdate.split('-')[2])
```

Comment: You've asked seven questions, but haven't accepted an answer to any of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14288498/1907098

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> starttime = datetime.strptime('2013-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> endtime = datetime.strptime('2013-01-04', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> [starttime + timedelta(days=i) for i in range((endtime - starttime).days + 1)]
[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 0, 0)]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), _))
['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04']
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

d1 = datetime.strptime('2013-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
d2 = datetime.strptime('2013-01-04', '%Y-%m-%d')

[d1 + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (d2 - d1).days + 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for:

```
from dateutil import parser as dateparser
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY

sd = dateparser.parse('2013-01-01')
ed = dateparser.parse('2013-01-04')

dates = (rrule(DAILY, sd, until=ed))
fmt = '{:%Y-%m-%d}'
print map(fmt.format, dates)
# ['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04']
```

Comment: This does introduce a dependency outside the Python stdlib though - but it's a useful one if dealing with DT's