# What is the equivalent of java DateRange in python

Tags: java, python, date-range

I have to re-write a Java project into a python library. I need to find the equivalent of DateRange type variables. What would be the closest data type to the DateRange type?

Comment: Here's a thread that discusses date ranges in python. It might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Comment: what is the exact class name? Is it `org.jfree.data.time.DateRange`?