# Writing a for loop in python that has the <= (smaller or equal) condition in it?

Tags: python-2.7, date, for-loop, less, equals

I want to iterate through different dates, for instance from 20/08/2015 to 21/09/2016, but I want to be able to run through all the days even if the year is the same. For instance 20/08/2015 to 25/09/2015.

Now if I write this in C, I could just use a for loop and make it so it runs if `value of startYear <= value of endYear`, but from all the examples I see online the for loop runs with the range function, which means if I give it the same start and end values it will simply not run.

For example:

```
startYear=int(raw_input("Starting year (yyyy):"));
endYear=int(raw_input("Ending year (yyyy):")); 
for year in range(startYear,endYear,1):
```

As the input comes from the user I have no control over it. So if `startYear` and `endYear` are both 2015 I can't make it iterate even once. Note that I can't "cheat" by changing the values of `startYear` and `endYear` as I am using the variable year for calculations later.

I would love to know:

1. Is there a way to run a for loop in Python that checks for lower or equal?
2. What is the best way to go about writing this simple iteration?

Thanks

Comment: What's the code you've tried and it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `endYear + 1` when calling `range`. Also note that passing `1` to the step argument is redundant.

   ```
   for year in range(startYear, endYear + 1):
   ```
2. You can use dates object instead in order to create a dates range, like in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24637447/1453822).

Comment: just to be clear if i run: for year in range(startYear ,endYear+1)

year would only have a value of startYear , run once then the for loop is finished 

am i correct ?

Comment: Thanks , 
i didn't think about it like that 
this is exactly what i wanted sometimes the easy things just do not appear in front of you
im sorry i cant affect the Answers' score but i up voted it 
thanks