# how to merge a range of datetime from list in python

Tags: python, datetime, merge, date-format

I want to ask a question. If I have list date like this:

```
'2017-03-23'
'2017-04-10'
'2017-04-11'
'2017-04-12'
'2017-04-13'
'2017-05-26'
'2017-05-27'
'2017-05-28'
```

then I want wrote those date to be like this:

```
'2017-03-23','2017-04-10 - 2017-04-13','2017-05-26 - 2017-05-28'
```

Please give an advise

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a range of dates in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

Comment: @jainishkapadia: Having similar words in the title doesn't mean those questions are duplicate. In this case, at all.

Answer (score 1):

sort all date first and merge it.
for example....

```
def merge(dates):
    ans = []
    dates.sort()
    for date in dates:
        if len(ans) == 0:
            ans.append(date)
        elif len(ans[-1]) == len('2017-04-10'):
            if ans[-1][:7] == date[:7]:
                ans[-1] += " - " + date
            else:
                ans.append(date)
        else:
            if ans[-1][-10:-3] == date[:7]:
                ans[-1] = ans[-1][:-2] + date[-2:]
            else:
                ans.append(date)
    return ans
```