# Convert List to formatted strings - update

Tags: python, model, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to write a python code that would automatically  give me a list from my choices attribute (drf)

that looks like this:

```
2011/2012
2012/2013
2013/2014
2014/2015
2015/2016
...
```

But I've failed brutally.
Below is my code (tho not doing anything reasonable)

```
x = xrange(2011, 2015)
y = xrange(2012, 2016)
z = '%5d / %5d' % (x, y) 
print '\n'.join(z)
```

Thanks for the help guys. 
There's one more thing
So I tried to put my out put in my choices attribute in my drf model, it's not giving me any error messages except that when I put

```
Print z
```

It includes the output in the console in the server when I run

```
Python manage.py runserver
```

This is my code below, I want to be sure that I'm doing the right thing

```
class studentship(models.Model):
      def datechoice():
             x = xrange(2011,2016)
             y = xrange(2012,2017)
             for tup in zip(x,y):
                    z = '%d/%d' %(tup[0], tup[1])

      pick_date = (datechoice())
      enroll = models.Charfield(max_Length = 1, choices = 
      pick_date, default = 'select school session')
```

Thanks guys for your help, I promise to improve my python hastily.

Comment: You should use a for-loop for this

Comment: Can you please reform your question? I really don't know what you really need... maybe use an example or something something else. Help us help you :)

Comment: Check here, probably is relevant to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Comment: Include the error message too in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use string formatting to get a list of strings. You have to explicitly write a for-loop:

```
x = xrange(2011, 2015)
y = xrange(2012, 2016)
z = ['%5d / %5d' % (a, b) for a,b in zip(x,y)] 
print '\n'.join(z)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this also worked perfectly, I'm a bit new to python.

Answer (score 0):

Though, your question is a bit unclear, try this:

```
for x in range(2011, 2016):
    print("{}/{}".format(x, x+1))
```

Output:

```
2011/2012
2012/2013
2013/2014
2014/2015
2015/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase each range by one year

```
x = xrange(2011, 2016) # 2016 is exclusive
y = xrange(2012, 2017)

# Use zip() to get tuples of years, one each from x and y
# print list(zip(x, y))
# [(2011, 2012), (2012, 2013), (2013, 2014), (2014, 2015), (2015, 2016)]

# Using zip(), loop through x and y
for tup in zip(x, y):
    z = '%d/%d' % (tup[0], tup[1])
    print z

2011/2012
2012/2013
2013/2014
2014/2015
2015/2016
>>>
```