# How to create a dataframe with 31 days in July

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I want to create a `df` which includes every day in 2019 July that looks like this:

```
      datetime
0   2019-07-01 00:00:00
1   2019-07-02 00:00:00
2   2019-07-03 00:00:00
3   2019-07-04 00:00:00
...
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: try pd.date_range('2019-07-01','2019-07-31',freq='D')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
m = '2019-07'
period = pd.Period(m, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = pd.date_range(start=period.start_time, end=period.end_time, freq='D')
```