# How to generate every single date MM/DD/YY in python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to generate every single birthday possible (365 possible birthdays) in python but have no idea how to do it. I tried making a value that counts up and stops at a certain number but that won't work!

what I mean is like this:
01 01 2020
01 02 2020
01 03 2020
M  D  Y

Etc

Any help works!

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

Comment: No not really but thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will get more high-quality answers if you attempt a solution and add it to your post. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?utm_source=Iterable&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=gen-welcome-email&utm_content=aug18 for advise on how to get the most useful answers from the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam gave you the solution you needed. For simplicity, you can try this:

```
dates = range(1, 32)
months = range(1, 13)
year = 2020

for i in months:
    for j in dates:
        print('{}/{}/{}'.format(i, j, year))
```

you can split 'dates' into two separate arrays of days 30 and 31 or you can apply check conditions for months not having 31 days. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
dates = [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
months = [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

for M in range(1, len(months)+1):
    for D in range(1, len(dates)+1):
        print("%d/%d/2020"%(D,M))
```

**Output:**

```
1/1/2020
2/1/2020
3/1/2020
4/1/2020
5/1/2020
6/1/2020
7/1/2020
8/1/2020
9/1/2020
10/1/2020
11/1/2020 ...
```

*As your question is so broad that is why I'm writing with nested loop to achieve your requirement.*