# Why was datetime removed from Pandas 1.0?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, deprecation-warning

I deal with a lot of data analysis in pandas and use pandas.datetime everyday. Lately I get the warning:

> *"FutureWarning: The pandas.datetime class is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import from datetime module instead."*

I've used Python datetime package before when pandas datetime wouldn't work with I wanted to do, and I understand it is a library that is more related to "date", but does anyone know the idea behind this shift to datetime package?

Comment: '1.0,1', pd.datetime.now()

Answer (score 32):

**Summary**: `datetime` (from the Python Standard Libary) was never really a part of Pandas or its API, which the developers are now making a concerted effort to warn about.  You can access the `datetime` class directly:

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

---

**Detail**: Older versions of Pandas ([example: 0.20](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.20.x/pandas/__init__.py)) contained:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

in `pandas/__init__.py`

This meant that, if you really wanted to, you could reference and use `pd.datetime`, which is really just the standard library's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html) class.

Per Pandas [issue #30610](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30296) and [issue #30296](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30610), `pandas.datetime` is really just standard `datetime.datetime`.  It looks like deprecating them (which, interesting, is done via [overriding `__getattr__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/28e0f18a30451601e8ac37b3ed75777bf1ed8f10/pandas/__init__.py#L194) at the module level*), is done to discourage "roundabout usage" where other 3rd party libraries/modules are brought into the top-level Pandas namespace.

That is, the Pandas library doesn't consider `datetime` (or `numpy`) being available in that namespace to be a part of its API, so you shouldn't depend on it being there in the first place.

---

*Specifically, this looks like:

```
# pandas/__init__.py
    def __getattr__(name):
        import warnings
        elif name == "datetime":
            warnings.warn(...)
            from datetime import datetime as dt
            return dt
```

Comment: So, only places where I need to make change  in my past codes is (a) `from datetime import datetime` and (b) replace `pd.datetime` with `datetime` ?

Comment: Brad, what about with multiIndices? For example,  pivot_table.index=[pandas.datetime(2012,month,day) for (month,day) in pivot_table.index] does not work anymore, if I substitute it by datetime