# I don't understand itertools.permutations (strange output)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, brute-force

Sorry to bother you with my stupidity...
I can't find how itertools.permutations work, the output is strange !
It is supposed to return all the possible combinations, like a bruteforce with a length defined for the output (a, b, c, ..., aa, ab, ac..., aaa, aab, aac... is a bruteforce, and permutations with 3 for exemple as length : aaa, aab, aac... dee, def, deg, ... zaa, zab, zac...), isn't it ?

But if I use "0123456789", sometimes values are missing, like 040613, and a lot are missing even if globally I got a loooot of values. So how does it work ?

If you want specifications, I try to get all possible dates at the format 050520 for exemple (may the second, 2020). But if dates are missing...

My code :

```py
from itertools import permutations #or combinations
def dates(charset, maxlength):
    return (''.join(candidate) for candidate in permutations(charset, maxlength))
print(list(dates("0123456789", 6)))
```

Thanks to all who will try to help me, have a nice day !

Comment: `'040613'` is not a permutation at all, so why should `itertools.permutations` generate it? My guess is that you want `itertools.product('0123456789',repeat = 6)`

Comment: "supposed to return all the possible combinations" - then you need to use `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: Do I want to bang my head realising how stupid I am ? Absolutely.

Comment: `aaa, aab, aac... dee, def, deg, ... zaa, zab, zac...` are not permutations with 3 for `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`.

Comment: @Austin yeah that was stupid from me but I took for exemple charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and then I use numbers ^^'

Answer (score 2):

The permutations of "0123456789" do not include "040613" since this number requires 2 of the zero token.

For example:

`>>> list(permutations("123", 3))
[('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '3', '2'), ('2', '1', '3'), ('2', '3', '1'), ('3', '1', '2'), ('3', '2', '1')]`

Does not contain "333" or "313"

Comment: You could expand your `charset`, which would create a lot more iteration cycles, and then filter these. Better solutions exist: https://stackoverflow.com/a/993367/9592055 `base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]`