# How to get all times within a time range

Tags: python, datetime, time

Using python, I want to get all the times within a range (24 hour time). How would I do this? 
If

```
start="10:00"
end="10:05"
```

Then I would want to get

```
["10:00","10:01","10:02","10:03","10:04","10:05"]
```

Comment: what if the times are in two different days?

Comment: what have you tried? are you using the `datetime` module at all?  A `datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)` would be a useful for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the date time module might be useful. Here's my idea for your problem if you were to use military time:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.time(10,0) # 10:00
end = datetime.time(10,5) # 10:05
TIME_FORMAT = "%H:%M" # Format for hours and minutes
times = [] # List of times 
while start <= end:
    times.append(start)
    if start.minute == 59: # Changes the hour at the top of the hour and set the minutes back to 0
        start = start.replace(minute=0) # have to use the replace method for changing the object
        start = start.replace(hour=start.hour + 1)
    else:
        start = start.replace(minute=start.minute + 1)
times = [x.strftime(TIME_FORMAT) for x in times] # Uses list comprehension to format the objects
print(times)
```