# Date Range in Python by List comprehension by multiple days

Tags: python, date, range, list-comprehension

So I’m trying to piggyback off Sandeep’s answer to create a range of dates in Python:
datetime - [Creating a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python) - and using a list comprehension to get a list of `datetime.dates` between two given `datetime.dates`.  Currently, it goes day by calendar day.  What I am trying to do is modify this to go  A) two days at a time (skip a day) and B) three days at a time (skip two days).   I believe it should be a modification to the range - I just can't get it right!

```
Import datetime
Start_date=datetime.date(2020,1,1)
End_date=datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
dd = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range((end_date-start_date).days + 1)]
print(dd)
```

proposed:

```
dd = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range((end_date-start_date).days + 1,datetime.timedelta(days=3))]
```

Which does not work, giving a TypeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object cannot be interpreted as an integer error.  Anyone can help?

Comment: Your passing a `datetime.timedelta(days=3)` object as the second argument to `range`. It's supposed to be an `int`, as the error implies

Answer (score 0):

The error as pointe out by juanpa.arrivllgaga user:5014455  is that in the list comprehension you are working with integers and not a datetime.date object, so keep things as integers.

Solution skipping N day between dates in the list:

```
N=3
dd = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0,(end_date-start_date).days + 1,N)]
dd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date.toordinal()` and `date.fromordinal()`:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

start_date = date.today()
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=15)
skip = 3

dd = [date.fromordinal(d) for d in range(start_date.toordinal(), end_date.toordinal(), skip)]
```