# How to create a list of datetime with knowing only the start, the number of iteration and timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have multiple dataframe with various number of rows.
I want to generate differents lists in order to create a column of datetime in every dataframe.

Each row of dataframe correspond to a half-hourly step, and the datetime format is `YYYYMMDD HHMMSS+0100`

At the end my output should be:

```
     Date
0    20210101 000000+0100
1    20210101 003000+0100
2    20210101 010000+0100
3    20210101 013000+0100
....
```

The difference with the problems I encounter on the internet is that I do not enter the end date.

Thanks for your help

Comment: so that is a column of string ? Because specific format only has sense for string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993358/creating-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

Comment: @azro At the end I will probably convert datetime into string if needed because I need this specific format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([('A', 'Q'), ('Z', 'S'), ('E', 'D'), ('R', 'F')])
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=len(df), freq='30min',
                           tz='Europe/Amsterdam').strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S%z')
```

```
   0  1                  date
0  A  Q  20210101 000000+0100
1  Z  S  20210101 003000+0100
2  E  D  20210101 010000+0100
3  R  F  20210101 013000+0100
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need

Comment: If using pandas then you can use `date_range` to do the above in one step... eg: `df['date'] = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=len(df), freq='30min', tz='Europe/Amsterdam').strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S%z')`